# Template type deduction in C++ for Class vs Function?

Tags: c++, class, function, templates, types

Why is that automatic type deduction is possible only for functions and not for Classes?

Comment: Do you talk about `std::vector a(1, true);` or about `std::vector<auto> v = std::vector<bool>(1, true);` ? The first will be "true" deduction, while the second will require an already known argument. Notice the complication of the bool-vector explicit specialization.

Comment: The first one, true deduction, is that not possible?

Comment: I just found Bjarne Stroustrups reasoning for not including this in the language.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In specific cases you could always do like `std::make_pair`:

```
template<class T>
make_foo(T val) {
    return foo<T>(val);
}
```

**EDIT:** I just found the following in "The C++ Programming Language, Third Edition", page 335. Bjarne says:

> Note that class template arguments are
>   never deduced. The reason is that the
>   flexibility provided by several
>   constructors for a class would make
>   such deduction impossible in many
>   cases and obscure in many more.

This is of course very subjective. There's been some discussion about this in `comp.std.c++` and the consensus seems to be that there's no reason why it *couldn't* be supported. Whether it would be a good idea or not is another question...

Comment: That is what I am asking why would you need to wrap a class inside a function, as like they do in boost::bind

Comment: The flexibility provided by several constructors is no less or more than the flexibility provided by several overloads.

Answer (score 10):

At [Kona meeting](https://isocpp.org/blog/2015/11/kona-standards-meeting-trip-report) Template parameter deduction for constructors ([P0091R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0091r0.html)) has been approved, which means that in C++17 <del>we'll be able to</del> we can write:

```
pair p1{"foo"s, 12};
auto p2 = pair{"foo"s, 12};
f(pair{"foo"s, 12});
```

Answer (score 4):

In case of a function call, the compiler deduces the template type from the argument type. For example the [std::max](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/)-function. The compiler uses the type of the arguments to deduce the template parameter. This does not allways work, as not all calls are unambigous.

```
int a = 5;
float b = 10;

double result1 = std::min( a, b ); // error: template parameter ambigous
double result2 = std::min< double >( a, b ); // explicit parameter enforces use of conversion
```

In case of a template class, that may not allways be possible. Take for instance this class:

```
template< class T>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
    void Bar( int a );
private:
    T m_Member;
};
```

The type T never appears in any function call, so the compiler has no hint at all, what type should be used.

Comment: So it's not always possible, but, as you point out, neither is it for functions. So that doesn't really explain why it isn't supported.

Comment: I do not know why it is not supported (a best-effort-solution would be conceivable), but the question was, if it is possible. I think i answered that, so I do not understand the downvote.

Comment: I think he asked *why* it's not possible, not *whether* it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think implicit type conversion is only applicable to function arguments only so compiler can deduce it to make the function call success.

But how can it deduce what type you wanna have it class.

We have to wait 4 such a day when we have **AI based compiler** to do read our minds.

Comment: -1 As far as I know, psychic powers are not part of any AI research program.  Plus, while I recognize that English is not everyone's first language, the abuse of '4' is unforgivable.

Comment: +1 said wait until the days when compilers can "know what you are trying to do" and be very reliable... it is a possibility. Just add a flag to the makefile.

Comment: No AI needed - GCC7 claims support for template argument deduction for class templates: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r3.html So just hold on a little longer. ;)