# C++ -- In which case the compiler can deduce the type

Tags: c++

```
vector<Widget*> vwp;

// populate vwp;

// Do need to specify the TYPE 'Widget'
for_each(vwp.begin(), vwp.end(), DeleteObject<Widget>()); // case I

template<typename T>
struct DeleteObject: public unary_function<const T*, void> {
    void operator() (const T* ptr) const
    {
      delete ptr;
    }
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

struct DeleteObjectB {
    template<typename T>
    void operator() (const T* ptr) const
    {
      delete ptr;
    }
};

vector<Widget*> vwpB;

// populate vwpB;

// Do not need to specify the TYPE 'Widget'
for_each(vwpB.begin(), vwpB.end(), DeleteObjectB()); // case II
```

My question is as follows:

```
In case I, we need to specify the type.
In case II, we don't need to specify the type.
Is there a general rule that I can follow?
```

Thank you

Comment: A related question is [Template type deduction in C++ for Class vs Function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921817/template-type-deduction-in-c-for-class-vs-function). You might want to have a quick look at that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first case features a class template.  The second case features a function template.  That is <s>the</s> one distinction.

Comment: @Oli, can I say in this way. Whenever we are in the class template, we should provide the type; whenever we are in the function template, we should not provide the type.

Comment: @Johannes: Class template arguments aren't derived.  Is that not correct?

Comment: @Johannes: But its constructor is a function (template).

Comment: The second case is a functor class.

Comment: Just because there are no template arguments after `DeleteObjectB` doesn't mean that `DeleteObjectB` is a function template. I can also not see any constructor template. Perhaps it's too late for me. But I'm really not seeing what you refer to.

Comment: @q0987: Class template arguments can never be deduced.  (But they can be defaulted.)  Function template arguments arguments can often be deduced, so you can sometimes omit them.  But sometimes you must or should provide them to help the compiler and/or make your code clearer.

Comment: @Johannes: Oh, sorry you're right.  It's not a constructor.  But the operator overload *is* a function template.

Comment: @Johannes: "The second case" features a function template.  Not "`DeleteObjectB` is a function template".

Comment: They are both functors. In the first case you have to instantiate the struct template first by definition, in the second case (as when you use function templates) there's limited type inference.

Comment: @aschepler: Thank you, yes, "features" is a better word.

Comment: @Oli I agree. I was confused by "The second case is a function template", since it sounds like you are saying that "DeleteObjectB" is a function template, and hence wouldn't need template arguments (when applying the (imo) reasonable assumption that "case" in both statements refers to the name appearing in the function argument). But that's not what you intend to say. Perhaps it's too late for me and I'm the only one confused by this.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: In the first case, you got nothing to deduce the template type from... how would you? :P In general, for class templates you need to specify the type and (correct me if I'm wrong) can never deduce it.
In your second case, the compiler can deduce the type because you pass an object of type `Widget*` to that `operator()`. That's how the compiler sees "Ah, incoming `Widget*` here, now I know what T should be!"

```
// Call:
DeleteObject deleter;
Widget* mypwidget;
deleter(mypwidget);
//      ^^^^^^^^^ -- of type `Widget*`, so `T` can be substituted with `Widget*`
```

Answer (score 0):

In case II, sometimes `operator()` is called statically polymorphic.
As you mentioned, probably case II is handier in many cases since compiler
can deduce the argument type.
However, in current C++, sometimes polymorphic `operator()` doesn't suit.
For example, if the `operator()` has the signature:

```
struct DeleteObjectB {
    template<typename T>
    T operator() (const T*) ...
```

then we cannot pass this `DeleteObjectB` to some *binder* like `std::bind1st`,
`boost::bind` or similar one.
Those binders require nested `typedef` `result_type` as the resultant
type of `operator()`.
So, in this case, we need case I.