# auto in template argument

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++14, auto

Consider the following code snippet:

```
template <class T>
struct S {
    S(const T&) {}
};

int main() {
    S<int> i{42}; // ok
    S<double> d(2.5); // ok
    S<auto> f = 0.5f; // fail. wants `float` for `auto`
    S<auto> l{10L}; // fail. wants `long` for `auto`
}
```

It's failed to compile with `c++14` option.

But I would like to know what is the real reason to forbid that in Standard.

My question is why it's not possible to use `auto` in template argument. I don't want to completely remove `<type>` from type's name as @yesraaj wants in his [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921817/template-type-deduction-in-c-for-class-vs-function#comment1828534_1921817) which marked as duplicate.

Futhermore, 6 years have passed (and 2 versions of c++ Standard was realeased) from that question's date. Many things have changed, I think.

Comment: it was approved for c++17 that automatic type deduction will work for constructing a template. E.g. this will work: `auto a = S{0.5f}`

Comment: @bolov can you give me a link with more information?

Comment: I posted an answer to the dupe question http://stackoverflow.com/a/34841082/2805305